# making UIBarButtonSystemItems appear in round rect buttons rather than just on their own

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm programmatically including an action button and a compose button on the toolbar with the following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *compose = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:7 target:self action:@selector(userWritesHaiku)];

compose.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

UIBarButtonItem *action = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:9 target:self action:@selector(userWritesHaiku)];

action.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

(And then putting them in an array and assigning them to the toolbar.)

But that gives me the following output:

[image: buttons created programmatically]

What I want is the following, which I can create with the Interface Builder, but I'm not using the Interface Builder.

[image: buttons created with Interface Builder]

How can I get the latter image programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item's `style` property has a default value of `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`.  You need to set it to `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`.

I tried this code in the iOS 5.0 simulator:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(self)];
//item.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
self.toolbar.items = [self.toolbar.items arrayByAddingObject:item];
```

I got this result:

[image: plain UIBarButtonItem]

Then I changed it to this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(self)];
item.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
self.toolbar.items = [self.toolbar.items arrayByAddingObject:item];
```

and I got this result:

[image: bordered UIBarButtonItem]

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought at first--but if you look in the code I posted, you'll see that I actually DID set the style to bordered--but it didn't do me any good.  :(

Comment: I think you must be doing something else to break it.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well, after I tinkered around, it works--I think I'd done something idiotic like set the button style in one method but then added the buttons from a different method, but I'm too embarrassed to find out for sure.  Thanks so much for your help!